# Errors in Hackerrank compare the triplets code

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, triplet

I was doing the hackerrank triplet sum question and I found these errors but I dont know why these errors are coming. Can someone please give a little more insight about it and if possible link a video about the topics I should read in order to atleast get the code correct.

**The code**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int compareTrip(int a[],int b[])
{
    int i=0,result1=0,result2=0;
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]>b[i])
        result1++;

        if(a[i]<b[i])
        result2++;

        else {
        return 0;
        }
    }
}
int main()
{
    int i,a[3],b[3];
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        cin>>a[i];
    }
    for(i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        cin>>b[i];
    }
    compareTrip(a[], b[]);

}
```

**The Errors**

```
Solution.cpp:30:19: error: expected primary-expression before ‘]’ token
     compareTrip(a[], b[]);
                   ^
Solution.cpp:30:24: error: expected primary-expression before ‘]’ token
     compareTrip(a[], b[]);
                        ^
Solution.cpp: In function ‘int compareTrip(int*, int*)’:
Solution.cpp:18:1: error: control reaches end of non-void function [-Werror=return-type]
 }
 ^
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You ought to work on simpler exercises awhile, in order to grasp the basics more firmly. The first two errors are about passing arrays as arguments; try `compareTrip(a,b)`. The third is about the return value of the function; it ought to return something, but doesn't. An introductory C++ text covers this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These first two errors occur because the compiler thinks you're trying to redefine the arrays `a` and `b`, which you've already initialized the at the beginning of `main`. When you call `compareTrip()` , you just need to pass in the names of those arrays as the two arguments.

The error `control reaches end of non-void function` indicates that there is no return value at the end of the function at line 18. So you have a set of if/else statements in `compareTrip()` , but it's possible that you might get two arrays of integers where there is no match between `a` and `b`, and the function does not account for this condition. If this edge case happens, we'd find ourselves in an infinite loop, because the function would leave the `for` statement and never `return`.  Because the `return` value is an int, you want to include a `return statement` outside of the for loop, before the final closing bracket `}`,to avoid an infinite loop.

You start learning more about C++ and its basic syntax through online courses like [https://www.learncpp.com/,](https://www.learncpp.com/), https://www.sololearn.com/Course/CPlusPlus/, and https://www.codecademy.com/learn/learn-c-plus-plus. I believe the first two are free, and the third lets you start with a free trial. Happy learning!

Comment: But I have added the condition else return zero in case above conditions dont match. Why is it still giving me error ? Also I removed the first two errors but still it is not displaying any answer. What do you think possibly is wrong in this code ? Help is much appreciated.

Comment: Why an infinite loop? Is that really what happens?

Answer (score 1):

```
static List<Integer> compareTriplets(List<Integer> a, List<Integer> b) {

    List<Integer> points=new ArrayList<Integer>(2); ;
    
    int apoint=0,bpoint=0;
    
    for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
    {
        if(a.get(i)>b.get(i))
        {
            apoint++;
        }
        else if(a.get(i)<b.get(i))
        {
            bpoint++;
        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
    points.add(0,apoint);
    points.add(1,bpoint);
    return points;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You should use `compareTrip(a,b);` instead of `compareTrip(a[], b[]);` as you are passing argument.
2. Your main function should return some value as it is interger type `int main()`.
   hope it helps.

Comment: The `main` function has an implicit `return 0;` if you don't provide one. The `compareTrip` function has a code path that can reach the end of the function without a `return`.